# Disable redirects in OkHttp3 for ONE request only

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I have a singleton (`object` in Kotlin) that holds an instance of `OkHttpClient` which as per the search on stack is the way to go.

Now I come to the scenario where for just ONE request in my app I need to skip the redirect to get the `Location` header.

It seems that the way to do it is via

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .followRedirects(false)
            .followSslRedirects(false)
            .build()
```

This is fine and dandy, but now I need to store two instances of `OkHttpClient` and the non-redirecting one is not even to be always used coz it pertains to a login flow for my app only.

Is it possible (e.g. via writing a network interceptor maybe?) to disable redirect for just ONE request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/), you should use one main instance, and then build customizations off of that base instance.

```
// renamed solely to make it clear what's going on below
val commonClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                   .followRedirects(true) // you can skip these calls, they are true by default
                   .followSslRedirects(true)
                   .build()
```

Then later on, in your "do login" function, you'd create a fork of the base client. Under the hood, everything will still use `commonClient` but any requests made using this "new" client will use the settings you overrode. It's just a bit of an odd, roundabout syntax.

```
// fork the base instance
val noRedirectClient = commonClient.newBuilder()
                       .followRedirects(false) // override the previous/default settings used by commonClient
                       .followSslRedirects(false)
                       .build()

// make your request(s)

// don't shutdown noRedirectClient, because it would also shutdown the
// underlying commonClient instance because they share resources
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this in a network interceptor.  Arguably @samthecodingman solution is cleaner, and it definitely works for "one" request.

But if you implement it as an interceptor then you don't need the client code to be aware.

See discussion here

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6871

Something like

```
      client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addNetworkInterceptor {
          it.proceed(it.request()).let { response ->
            if (request.url.encodedPath == "foo") {
              response.newBuilder()
                .removeHeader("Location")
                .build()
            } else {
              response
            }
          }
        }
```